# attempt to call field 'read' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I'm playing with Lua following the link: https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.3.html. Now I was confused with the use of 'read' in the code.

```
> repeat
line=os.read()
until line ~=""
stdin:2: attempt to call field 'read' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It was a typo. It's fixed now. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could argue that this is because PIL was written for Lua 5.0 and you are most likely using version higher than that. However, [Lua 5.0 Reference Manual 5.7](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#5.7) clearly states that there is no such function in `os`.

Long story short: it's a mistake not covered by any errata for the online version of PIL (or, you know, since it's online they could just fix it).

Use [`io.read`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.read) instead.